# Finding how to use "rank" or other similar grouping functions with conditionals in R

Tags: r, date, ranking, rank

I am trying in R to perform a ranking or grouping with the following characteristics:

- The content of the field: "Object" of the following record is equal to the content of the field: "Object"
- The date of the next record is sequential (corresponds to the next day)

Example data:

| OBJECT | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| PRODUCT1 | 01/02/2023 |
| PRODUCT1 | 02/02/2023 |
| PRODUCT1 | 21/02/2023 |
| PRODUCT2 | 07/02/2023 |
| PRODUCT2 | 09/02/2023 |
| PRODUCT2 | 10/02/2023 |
| PRODUCT2 | 11/02/2023 |
| PRODUCT2 | 23/02/2023 |

I am using the following code but the result is not correct:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(object), transform, rank = (seq_along(date)))
```

The expected result is similar to the following table:

| OBJECT | DATE | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCT1 | 01/02/2023 | 1 |
| PRODUCT1 | 02/02/2023 | 1 |
| PRODUCT1 | 21/02/2023 | 2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 07/02/2023 | 1 |
| PRODUCT2 | 09/02/2023 | 2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 10/02/2023 | 2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 11/02/2023 | 2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 23/02/2023 | 3 |

I appreciate your help in solving this question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: `plyr` has been retired from active development for some years. I'd suggest 1) convert your date column to R's Date data type (which is always YYYY-MM-DD) 2) use `library(dplyr); df |> mutate(rank = cumsum(coalesce(date > lag(date) + 1)), .by = Object)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranking groups by "object" and orders by "date". The wanted value is then based on if the gap between the previous row and the current row is greater than 1 day, then the rank is incremented by 1.

```
df <- data.frame(OBJECT = c("PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT2"),
                 DATE = as.Date(c("2023-02-01", "2023-02-02", "2023-02-21", "2023-02-07", "2023-02-09", "2023-02-10", "2023-02-11", "2023-02-23")))

library(dplyr)

# add the wanted column
df <- df %>%
  group_by(OBJECT) %>%
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  mutate(wanted = cumsum(c(1, diff(DATE) > 1)))

df

|  OBJECT  |    DATE    | wanted |
+----------+------------+--------+
| PRODUCT1 | 2023-02-01 |      1 |
| PRODUCT1 | 2023-02-02 |      1 |
| PRODUCT1 | 2023-02-21 |      2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 2023-02-07 |      1 |
| PRODUCT2 | 2023-02-09 |      2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 2023-02-10 |      2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 2023-02-11 |      2 |
| PRODUCT2 | 2023-02-23 |      3 |
```

Comment: thank you very much... at first I thought it wasn't working but it was ordering the data frame again. Thank you

Comment: thanks - yes - the order isn't as expected, but the calculation correct - cheers

Comment: Two friendly remarks: First this will also work: `library(dplyr) library(lubridate) df %>% 
  mutate(RANK = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dmy(DATE)) != 1)), .by=OBJECT)`. Second I think we have to use `.by_group = TRUE` in arrange in your example. -> `df %>%
  mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE)) %>% 
  group_by(OBJECT) %>%
  arrange(DATE, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(wanted = cumsum(c(1, diff(DATE) > 1)))`